# How do I cancel $interval only on leaving a state in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

The idea is for a modal to open on a specific page after the user has been on it for 10 seconds, and cancel it if the user leaves the page. It works when I refresh the page, but when I navigate to the page my code cancels the $interval when it is loaded.

In my controller:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) { 
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        });

$scope.openmodal = function () {
        interval = $interval(function () {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
              animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
              templateUrl: 'modal.html',
              controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
              size: 'lg',
            });             
        }, 10000, [1]);         
    }

$scope.openmodal();
```

The problem is the the $locationChangeStart is executed when the state is loaded coming from a different state. When I just refresh the browser the $locationChangeStart doesn't run and the modal will open after 10 seconds. How do I stop my controller from calling the $interval.cancel() method when loading from a different state?

Comment: Tried using $stateChangeStart instead? Or even better $stateChangeSuccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() { 
    $interval.cancel(interval);
});
```

Please read `ui-router`'s docs specifically the [events](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events) section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the timer each time a new state is loaded in the controller of the state. If user remains on the state , the modal will be displayed. 
But if user leaves the state before opening the modal you need to cancel the timer as the new state will again be initiating a new instance of the timer.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
            $interval.cancel(interval);
        });
var interval = $interval(function () {
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'modal.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: 'lg',
        });             
    }, 10000, [1]);
```